# What's the relationship between index.html and JavaScript files in src in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm confused with the React files, I can't understand how the `index.html` in `public` folder connects to JS files in `src` folder without using any `script` tags?

I deleted all the files in `src` file and created a new JS file called it `a.js` then when I ran `npm start`, it gave the error below:

Code:

```
//a.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

const root1 = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root1.render(

<h2>hey</h2>
);
```

Error:

```
Could not find a required file.

  Name: index.js

  Searched in: D:\counter-app\src
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Exactly what it tells you is going on - `src/index.js` is _required_ (this is specifically called out on e.g. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/folder-structure). That's what Webpack, which also injects the necessary script tags when building the _output_ version of `index.html`, is configured to look for.

Comment: As @jonrsharpe says, React projects have a build step in which a bundler like Webpack or Vite packages up all your javascript into a single* javascript file and injects a `<script>` tag into your index.html to load it. Your bundler is configured to look for `index.js` as the entry point into your code. (*It's not _necessarily_ a single javascript output file but for the purposes of this discussion I'm ignoring code splitting.)